# Serializing a list of objects in a object

Tags: java, jaxb

I have two java classes defined as follows

```
public class Field {
    public String fieldName;        
}
public class Record {
    public String name;
    public List<Field> fieldList;
}
```

I tried to use jaxb to serialize a Record object:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Record.class);
Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(new JAXBElement(new QName("", Record.class.getSimpleName()),
                          Record.class, record),
          serializedValue);
```

I was expecting the object to get serialized as follows

```
<Record>
  <name>Test</name>
  <fieldList>
    <Field>
      <fieldName>Test1</fieldName>
    </Field>
  </fieldList>
</Record>
```

But I got xml as follows

```
<Record>
  <name>Test</name>
  <fieldList>
    <fieldName>Test1</fieldName>
  </fieldList>
</Record>
```

Why is this happening? How do I get the `Field` tag to show up in the serialized xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you have a List or Set  you have to declare two tags **@XmlElementWrapper** and **@XmlElement**:-

```
public class Record {
    public String name;
    public List<Field> fieldList;


    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "fieldList")
    // XmlElement sets the name of the entities in collection
    @XmlElement(name = "Field")
   public void setFieldList(List<Field> fieldList)
  {
    this.fieldList = fieldList;
  }


}
```

Comment: sorry for the earlier typo

Comment: Thanks.. this worked. Why JAXB is not able to figure this out without the additional annotations?

Comment: @chimanrao - By default JAXB does it  not wrap collections in a grouping element so you need metadata to cause this to happen.  Another library such as XStream wraps collections by default, but requires metadata supplied to not wrap it.